# How to show output in HTML instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT83w.png)I am using a jquery script to show the page content on a scroll of page, which is working fine but I'm facing issues in output content.

It is showing my all loops data in text form, not in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    
    var $loading = $('<div class="loading"><img class="loading-icon" src="https://crazyoffers.today/static/media/Spinner-Preloader.2b02159f.gif" width="25"></div>');
var $icon = $loading.find('img');
var $content = $('.content');
var $p = $content.find('p');
var CHUNK_SIZE = 2000;

$content.append($loading);

var block = 0;
var loading = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (block === -1) {
        return;
    }
    
    if (!loading && (window.scrollY + $(window).height() - 30) > ($p.offset().top + $p.outerHeight())) {
        loading = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $icon.show();
            load(function () {loading = false});
        }, 250);
    }
});

var $text = $('.text').html();
var p = '';

function load(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var str = $text.text().slice(block * CHUNK_SIZE, (block + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE);
        p = p + str;
        
        block++;
        if (block * CHUNK_SIZE >= $text.length) {
            block = -1;
        }

        $p.text(p + (block === -1 ? '(No More Events)' : '...'));
        $icon.hide();
        
        cb();
    }, 750);
}

load();
});
</script>
```

The above script I have used to use scroll effect to page content, but out is displaying all HTML tags along with content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery.text() method to output the contents.

```
$p.text(p + (block === -1 ? '(No More Events)' : '...'));
```

Try using [`jQuery.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) instead

Comment: Please check the image when I use .html() then it is showing complete text all design and images are removed

Comment: Does the code you are trying to append is a valid HTML? From your code, it seems that you are slicing HTML based on length, not structure

Comment: Yes I have added for each loop to get the content and all content is added in proper div structure

Comment: This seems a bit odd approach. Why don't you include all your posts (events) as a JSON in the HTML for easier processing at the frontend?